# Use of cute tagging, tag abuse? [ef] [include]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

The [include](/questions/tagged/include) tag is about compilation, like C++ or LESS includes.

The EF extension method that controls pre-loading or lazy-loading tables/objects is called `.Include()`.  I just retagged a question because it used the [include](/questions/tagged/include) tag on a question about this method.

Then I checked, and there are 30 other EF questions that abuse the [include](/questions/tagged/include) tag the same way.

The `.Include()` method is important in EF, but this use of tagging, while cute, IMO is tag abuse.

1. Is it tag abuse?
2. If not, can my edit be rolled-back?
3. Should the [include](/questions/tagged/include) tag mention this 'cute' usage, to avoid retagging noise like this?

Here is the revision I would prefer to rollback (yzorg, today, 1/29):
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3356541/revisions

Here are the other 30 uses of the [include](/questions/tagged/include) tag on [ef](/questions/tagged/ef) questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework+include

Comment: What about that usage is "cute".  "wrong" seems like a much more appropriate term.

Comment: I changed the phrase '30 abuses' to '30 uses', since there doesn't seem to be a consensus whether this is abuse or not.  If it is abuse the consensus is the number of uses is too low to be worth creating a dedicated tag, which is the best fix.

Comment: Actually, I don't think anyone but you thinks that this is abuse.  Everyone that has addressed that seems to feel that this is an innocent mistake and not intentional abuse.  I would say that there is consensus on that point.

Comment: The tag [tag:lazy-loading] seems much more appropriate than [tag:include] for questions about the EF `.Include()` method.

Comment: @Servy Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @Servy I initially used 'cute' instead of 'wrong' as a hedge to animuson's reading of the tag - he isn't sure [tag:include] is even wrong in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's not really *abuse*.  Abuse would imply that it's malicious; that they're trying to cause problems.  This is simply an inadvertent mistake.  Looking at the percentage of questions that have their tags edited, mistakes such as this (using tag that sounds similar, but is in fact on an unrelated topic) is not abuse, it's just a common mistake that is easily fixed (by all means, fix it).  In this particular case you can look a [the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/include/info) to see the definition of that tag.  It is not relevant to that EF question.  This is *precisely* what tag wikis are there for; to help people determine which meaning of a particular word/phrase the tag applies to.
2. You do not need to roll back the edit.
3. I don't see a need to; this doesn't appear to be a significant enough problem to warrant such behavior.  30 incorrect questions out of over 3000 is less than a 1% failure rate.  If it was something like 5-10% I'd be more concerned.

The next question that you didn't ask is whether we should create a new tag that *does* represent this usage of `Include` with respect to EF.  Personally, I don't see the need for such a tag as it shouldn't represent a *lot* of questions, nor does it seem to be particularly valuable information to get out of a tag.  If you feel it would make a good tag, feel free to make it or propose having it made.

Answer (score 4):

It's not abuse, just a misunderstanding. People type words with spaces:

```
ef include
```

as though that was a single tag. What they end up with is:

[ef](/questions/tagged/ef) [include](/questions/tagged/include)

If there was an [ef-include](/questions/tagged/ef-include) (should volume warrant it) they *might* see that while they were typing, but then again, they might not. Characterizing this behaviour as either "cute" or "abuse" is really unhelpful. It suggests the poster knows exactly how the tag system works, and its design, and is deliberately using it contrary to design, just to achieve something the system didn't want them to achieve. I don't believe that's the case at all. The tagging system confuses some people, and as good caretakers, we should fix the results of that confusion when we spot it.

Comment: I think the other answers make the same assumptions I did about the use of the [tag:include] being intentionally cute.  I don't see how asking this question on meta can be deemed 'really unhelpful', but I could see how leaving such feedback as a comment to the question could be.  :)  Yes, now I'm being intentionally cute, or trying to.

Comment: your question isn't really unhelpful. But the parts of it that use "abuse" instead of "mistake" create an emotional tone that doesn't help solve the problem, which is mistagged questions

Answer (score 3):

> The [include](/questions/tagged/include) tag is about compilation, like C++ or LESS includes.

Where did you come up with that? Include is a very common function used in just about *every* programming language. Here's the tag wiki excerpt for it:

> A provision that many programming languages provide to allow code (functions, classes, objects) in one file to be used in many others.

Comment: So you think it is appropriate use of the [tag:include] when the question is about an ORM method call?

Comment: All the uses in the wiki excerpt you quote seem to be code constructs, not database constructs.  It didn't seem appropriate for use with a specific ORM method call just because the name of the method matched the name of the tag.  The tag [tag:lazy-loading] seems much more appropriate.

Comment: I personally have no idea. I'm not familiar with EF. I was simply pointing out that your evaluation of the tag's use was completely inaccurate.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know it's a misuse of tags but if it is, then there are other cases:

1. `.Include()` it's a LINQ feature, and LINQ `!=` Entity Framework, so there other questions. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14477389/422353))
2. There is also a `:include` method in Rails ActiveRecord and corresponding questions ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4047833/422353)). Sadly, some Rails questions in [include](/questions/tagged/include) are indeed about file inclusion (using Ruby `require`).

And I didn't an extensive search so there might be other things.

Comment: I wanted to add the 'include' tag to your question but I don't have enough rep!